# Nginx inputstream ssk offloading

Tags: ssl, nginx

WHen using NginX for ssl offloading things work fine, however when trying to do this for serialized stream over a socket it seems to work incorrectly, and the documentation over using streams http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_module.html makes no sense,

can anyone help me with a working foo bar example of how to ssl offload for a streaming input(made of serialized logging event objects in this case) with nginx

Edit:

we are trying to forward and strip SSL off of log4j socketappender output but cannot even get the forwarding working when the SSL is not enabled.

```
here is the config file without the ssl offloading portion(when retrieving non https the forwarding still does not work correctly)
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 4560 ;
    server_name logstash.corelims.com;



    location / {
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:4561/;
      proxy_redirect http://localhost:4561/ http://logstash.corelims.com:4560/;
    }
        error_log C:/ELK/nginx-1.9.4/logs/debug.log debug;
  }
}
```

which leads us to these debug logs:

```
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [info] 5052#3716: *45 WSARecv() failed (10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) while reading client request line, client: IP.ADDRESS.HIDDENFOR.POST, server: foo.bar.com, request: "¬í "
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [debug] 5052#3716: *45 lingering read: -1
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [debug] 5052#3716: *45 http request count:1 blk:0
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [debug] 5052#3716: *45 http close request
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [debug] 5052#3716: *45 http log handler
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [debug] 5052#3716: *45 free: 008DE8E8, unused: 1991
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [debug] 5052#3716: *45 close http connection: 300
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [debug] 5052#3716: *45 event timer del: 300: 1822859279
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [debug] 5052#3716: *45 select del event fd:300 ev:0
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [debug] 5052#3716: *45 reusable connection: 0
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [debug] 5052#3716: *45 free: 023BCED0
2015/08/27 00:54:59 [debug] 5052#3716: *45 free: 023BEEA8, unused: 24
2015/08/27 12:27:45 [debug] 5052#3716: select del event fd:316 ev:0
```

Comment: What does 'seems to work incorrectly' mean? In particular, what do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: explain what is not working. for example: screenshots, code examples, error messages...

Comment: post edited to display more information, thanks guys